# RxJS / Redux-observables: How would I test EventEmitter?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to test that redux actions are fired when the finish event on my upload object is fired.

Here's my epic:

```
const uploadFileEpic = (action$, state$, dependencies$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(uploadActions.UPLOAD_FILE),
    mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
      const { file, masterHandle } = payload;

      return new Observable(o => {
        const upload = masterHandle.uploadFile("/", file);
        const handle = upload.handle;

        upload.on("finish", () => {
          o.next(
            uploadActions.uploadSuccess({
              masterHandle
            })
          );
          o.complete();
        });
      });
    })
  );
```

Here is what I have written so far. It doesn't work:

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toArray";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

import uploadActions from "../actions/upload-actions";
import uploadEpic from "./upload-epic";

test("uploadFilesEpic filesActions.UPLOAD_FILE on success", done => {
  const file = { name: "f1" };
  const upload = new EventEmitter();
  upload.handle = "h1";

  const masterHandle = {
    uploadFile: jest.fn(() => upload)
  };

  const action$ = of(uploadActions.uploadFile({ file, masterHandle }));

  upload.emit("finish");

  uploadEpic(action$).subscribe(actions => {
    expect(actions).toEqual(uploadActions.uploadSuccess({ masterHandle }));
    done();
  });
});
```

It says the async callback was not fired:

```
 FAIL  src/redux/epics/upload-epic.test.js (8.531s)
  ✓ uploadFilesEpic filesActions.UPLOAD_FILES (9ms)
  ✕ uploadFilesEpic filesActions.UPLOAD_FILE on success (5021ms)

  ● uploadFilesEpic filesActions.UPLOAD_FILE on success

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      23 | });
      24 |
    > 25 | test("uploadFilesEpic filesActions.UPLOAD_FILE on success", done => {
         | ^
      26 |   const file = { name: "f1" };
      27 |   const upload = new EventEmitter();
      28 |   upload.handle = "h1";

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Object.test (src/redux/epics/upload-epic.test.js:25:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.297s
```

It makes sense to me that the test is failing but I'm not sure how to subscribe to the epic, fire the `finish` event, and then inspect the actions returned by the epic.

Comment: Try moving `upload.emit("finish")` to the bottom of the test.

Comment: @Reactgular wow that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event for finishing the upload is emitted too early in the test. The `EventEmitter` does not keep a *buffer* of events and if no one is subscribed, then the even is lost.

Move the emit `"finish"` to the bottom of the test.

```
upload.emit("finish"); // must emit after subscribing
```